Compute shader based Particle System
I'm experimenting with compute shaders and wrote the particle system.
The emit shader now takes particle data from the constant buffer because I don't have randomizing functions implemented yet. That's why it only uses 1 thread. I'll fix it later.
There's no sorting, but it's ok since it's just a simple system.
Could you review this code and give me feedback, please? I'm not sure if I should use one RWByteAddressBuffer to store data for every indirect command and use offset in context->DispatchIndirect/context->DrawInstancedIndirect or if it's ok to have separate buffers.
Also, maybe you'll spot something I did wrong. I'd appreciate any comment
Particle.hlsli
static const uint MAX_PARTICLES = 1024;

static const uint PARTICLE_THREADCOUNT_EMIT = 64;
static const uint PARTICLE_THREADCOUNT_UPDATE = 256;

struct Emitter
{
    float4 color;
    float3 position;
    float emitCount;
};

struct Particle
{
    float4 color;
    float3 position;
    float rotation;
    float3 speed;
    float pad;
    //.x - current frame lifetime, 0 at the beginning
    //.y - per particle random max lifetime
    //.z - global max lifetime - the same for all particles 
    float3 lifetime;
    float pad2;
    float2 size;
    float2 growthSpeed;
    uint frame;
    float frameFraction;
    float2 pad3;
    
    float getCurrentLifetime()
    {
        return lifetime.x;
    }
    
    float getThisMaxLifetime()
    {
        return lifetime.y;
    }
    
    float getGlobalMaxLifetime()
    {
        return lifetime.z;
    }
    
    bool isAlive()
    {
        return lifetime.x < lifetime.z;
    }
};

struct Counters
{
    uint activeCount;
    uint activeCountAfterUpdate;
    uint offset;
    uint expiredCount;
};

#ifdef PARTICLE_WRITE

RWStructuredBuffer<Counters> counter : register(u0);
RWStructuredBuffer<Particle> particles : register(u1);

RWByteAddressBuffer indirectDispatchEmit : register(u2);
RWByteAddressBuffer indirectDispatchUpdate : register(u3);
RWByteAddressBuffer indirectDraw : register(u4);

cbuffer EmitterBuffer : register(b2)
{
    Emitter emitter;
}

#elif defined(PARTICLE_READ)

StructuredBuffer<Counters> counter : register(t20);
StructuredBuffer<Particle> particles : register(t21);

#endif

uint getIndex(uint id)
{
    return (counter[0].offset + id) % MAX_PARTICLES;
}

Emit.hlsl
#define PARTICLE_WRITE
#include "Particle.hlsli"

cbuffer NewParticle : register(b3)
{
    Particle newParticle;
};

[numthreads(1, 1, 1)] //use PARTICLE_THREADCOUNT_EMIT for .x
void CSMain(uint globalThreadID : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
    if (globalThreadID  >= (uint)emitter.emitCount)
        return;

    uint activeIndex;
    InterlockedAdd(counter[0].activeCount, 1, activeIndex);
    
    uint index = getIndex(activeIndex);  
    particles[index] = newParticle;
}

Update.hlsl
#define PARTICLE_WRITE
#include "../Common/PerFrame.hlsli"
#include "Particle.hlsli"

void DepthCollision(inout Particle particle);
void Update(inout Particle particle, const float dt);

groupshared Particle sharedParticles[PARTICLE_THREADCOUNT_UPDATE];

[numthreads(PARTICLE_THREADCOUNT_UPDATE, 1, 1)]
void CSMain(uint globalThreadID : SV_DispatchThreadID, uint localThreadID : SV_GroupID)
{
    const uint activeCount = counter[0].activeCount;
    if (globalThreadID >= activeCount)
        return;
    
    const uint particleIndex = getIndex(globalThreadID);
    sharedParticles[localThreadID] = particles[particleIndex];
    
    GroupMemoryBarrierWithGroupSync();
    
    Update(sharedParticles[localThreadID], time.y);
    
    if (sharedParticles[localThreadID].isAlive()) {
        InterlockedAdd(counter[0].activeCountAfterUpdate, 1);
    } else {
        InterlockedAdd(counter[0].expiredCount, 1);
    }

    GroupMemoryBarrierWithGroupSync();
    
    particles[particleIndex] = sharedParticles[localThreadID];
}

void Update(inout Particle particle, const float dt)
{
    particle.position += particle.speed * dt;
    particle.size += particle.growthSpeed * dt;
    
    particle.frameFraction = 1.0f - (particle.getCurrentLifetime() / particle.getThisMaxLifetime());
    particle.frame = (uint) (particle.frameFraction * 64);
    
    particle.lifetime.x += dt;
    
    float normalizedLifetime = particle.getCurrentLifetime() / particle.getThisMaxLifetime();
    particle.color.a = max(2.0f * (normalizedLifetime < 0.5f ? normalizedLifetime : 1.0f - normalizedLifetime), 0.0f);
}

Finish.hlsl
#define PARTICLE_WRITE
#include "../Common/IndirectCommands.hlsli"
#include "Particle.hlsli"

[numthreads(1, 1, 1)]
void CSMain()
{
    const uint activeCount = counter[0].activeCountAfterUpdate;
    
    counter[0].offset = (counter[0].offset + counter[0].expiredCount) % MAX_PARTICLES;
    counter[0].expiredCount = 0;
    
    counter[0].activeCount = activeCount;
    counter[0].activeCountAfterUpdate = 0;
 
    //uncomment when the emit shader will emit more than 1 particle
    //DispatchIndirectCommand indirectEmitCmd;
    //indirectEmitCmd.x = ceil(emitter.emitCount / (float) PARTICLE_THREADCOUNT_EMIT);
    //indirectEmitCmd.y = 1;
    //indirectEmitCmd.z = 1;
    //indirectEmitCmd.Store(indirectDispatchEmit);    

    DispatchIndirectCommand indirectUpdateCmd;
    indirectUpdateCmd.x = ceil(((float) activeCount + emitter.emitCount) / (float) PARTICLE_THREADCOUNT_UPDATE);
    indirectUpdateCmd.y = 1;
    indirectUpdateCmd.z = 1;
    indirectUpdateCmd.Store(indirectDispatchUpdate);
    
    DrawArraysIndirectCommand drawCmd;
    drawCmd.count = 4;
    drawCmd.instanceCount = activeCount;
    drawCmd.first = 0;
    drawCmd.baseInstance = 0;
    drawCmd.Store(indirectDraw);
}

particle vertex shader
#define PARTICLE_READ
#include "Particle.hlsli"

struct VertexInput
{
    uint vertexID : SV_VertexID;
    uint instanceID : SV_InstanceID;
};

VertexOutput VSMain(VertexInput input)
{
    VertexOutput output;
    
    Particle particle = particles[getIndex(input.instanceID)];
    
    //... not important
}

